# using variables within a telnet session

Tags: linux, bash, telnet

I havea  script that I use to send multiple commands using a telnet session.  I'm not sure if I need escape characters or not.  If I type the command directly in the telnet session, it works and I get the expected response.  However when I place it in the script it doesn't work.

And the really odd part is that I've put one of the commands in echo and I get the same back as I do from the telnet prompt...this leads me to believe I need to escape some character, but which has been my issue.

I've attempted using sleep commands however that really doesn't seem to change anything...

Here's the snippet:

```
pushSAT() {
    #This is what the command should look like:
    #EPHM:FPSH,satellite,ephemeris_code,file_name,cmd_action<cr><lf>

    HOST=$1
    SATS=( $(grep O3B_M* $DIR/$FILE2ACU) )

    for i in "${SATS[@]}"
    do
       echo "$i"
       echo "EPHM:FPSH,$i,202,$FILE2ACU,@"; 
       (sleep 2
        echo "EPHM:FPSH,$i,202,$FILE2ACU,@";
        sleep 1
        echo "TGTS:FLST,?";
        sleep 1
        echo "^]";
        sleep 1
        echo "logout";
       ) | telnet $HOST 6100 | tee acuresponse.txt

       log user.info "Pushed $FILE2ACU to $HOST for $i."
    done
}
```

Here's the response from echo as well as telnet; notice where it's cut off... odd!

```
Loading satellites to ant-3-acu
O3B_M001
,202,ephemeris.txt,@"
```

This is where the issue lies; why is this getting cut off?

And, this is what I expect from the command that's failing:

```
Connected to ant-3-acu (ip).
Escape character is '^]'.
EPHM:FPSH,O3B_M001,202,ephemeris.txt,@
ephm:fpsh,0,0
```

Comment: There are signs of `\r\n`-pair and whitespace issues. Could you post a few lines that would be output by your `grep` command?

Comment: You may also want to look into the [`expect`](http://www.nist.gov/el/msid/expect.cfm) utility.

Comment: @chepner Telnet takes care of \r\n on the wire completely, and it should understand the same newline as (keyboard) input that echo uses on output surely?

Comment: I'm less worried about `telnet` than I am about the contents of the file that feeds the `SATS` array. I was under the impression that `Loading satellites....` et al was from the first pair of `echo` statements, not the one whose output is piped to `telnet`.

Comment: @chepner Yes, I see, there is a rogue newline inside $i.

Comment: Hi @Chepner-  Thanks for the help.  The SATS array returns this "O3B_M00x", the file I'm pull this from is an ephemeris file that looks liek this:
O3B M001
1 00001U 001001   13134.54166667  .00000000  00000+0  00000+0 0 00018
2     1   0.0399 359.0429 0028976 145.2061 239.3456  5.02804648    06
O3B M002
1 00002U 002001   13134.00000000  .00000000  00000+0  00000+0 0 00020

I didn't realize the "echo $i" would be a problem.  It was there for me to verify the informationfrom the file above.  I'll remove it.

I'm certainly not a bash afficionado...and definitely appreciate the help!

Comment: @Chepner-  Just following up on your "Loading Satellites..." question.  The function above is called by this piece:

echo "Loading satellites to $DEST..."
 pushSAT "$DEST"

Since I have a few variations on how this is called, I decided it best to use a function.  The "DEST" is always the same.  Hope this answers your question.

Again, appreciate any recommendations...

Comment: @ Chepner- Here's the output from the grep:

Loading satellites to ant-3-acu...
O3B_M001
O3B_M002
O3B_M003
O3B_M004
O3B_M005
O3B_M006
O3B_M007
O3B_M008
Trying <1p>...
Connected to ant-3-acu

Comment: The problem isn't the `echo` itself, but that your array doesn't have one element per item; it has multiple items per line, because each run of whitespace starts a new element.

Answer (score 0):

^] means control/]. You aren't sending that correctly. Sending it as literal text "^]" won't work. So the logout probably never happens.

Whatever the remaining problems, and I'm sure they exist, I doubt that they have anything to do with your title. Your question is really just about scripting.

Comment: This is one, but probably not the only, problem.

Answer (score 0):

This may not fix all the problems, but it will be a start. Since your input file has whitespace, you need to change how you read it.

Changes

1. Use a `while` loop to read a single line at a time from the output of `grep`.
2. Removed semicolons (they weren't hurting anything, but they are unnecessary
3. Use printf to print a proper control character in place of the literal string "^]"

One other issue: if your input file has DOS line endings, you'll need to remove them with a program like `dos2unix`, since they will not be stripped by the `read` command.

---

```
pushSAT() {
    #This is what the command should look like:
    #EPHM:FPSH,satellite,ephemeris_code,file_name,cmd_action<cr><lf>

    HOST=$1
    grep 'O3B_M*' "$DIR/$FILE2ACU" | while read -r line;
    do
       echo "$line"
       echo "EPHM:FPSH,$line,202,$FILE2ACU,@"
       (sleep 2
        echo "EPHM:FPSH,$line,202,$FILE2ACU,@"
        sleep 1
        echo "TGTS:FLST,?"
        sleep 1
        printf "\035\n"
        sleep 1
        echo "logout"
       ) | telnet $HOST 6100 | tee acuresponse.txt

       log user.info "Pushed $FILE2ACU to $HOST for $line."
    done
}
```